# Select rows matching a pattern using LIKE

Tags: oracle, wildcard, sql-like

I am using an oracle-database with data having a string-attribute consisting of any valid XML. This XML looks like the following:

```
<tag><t1>[someIntValue]</t1><moreTags>...</moreTags></tag>
```

Now I want to select rows that do **not** have a particular value for `someIntValue`. I tried it out by using `attr NOT LIKE '%<t1>1600</t1>%'` where 1600 is the value I do not want to be selected. But the former also gives me rows that do not even have this tag . Is there any wildcard that negates the pattern (something like `attr LIKE '%<t1>![1600]</t1>%'`)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ...
from ....
where attr like '%<t1>%</t1>%' 
and attr not like '%<t1>1600</t1>%'
```

Someone who's quicker than me with regular expressions might give you a better answer, but this one should work well enough.

Comment: Well regex´ won´t work within LIKE as far as I know, so your solution should work indeed. I varify it currently, but needs much time to perform the query...

Comment: Oracle introduced regex support in 10g I think. The REGEXP_LIKE operator might help if you can come up with the expression. Thanks for accepting my answer anyway.

Comment: Good hint, that´s what I was looking for. Well, I accepted your answer because it solves my problem, although not exactly in the way I expected but it DID.